# Point pattern gradient fill

Tags: qgis, point, fill

I'm trying to create a point pattern gradient fill for some polygons, because I don't want harsh boundaries. The boundaries should blend in with the background.

[image: Example of point pattern gradient fill]

Since I use open streetmap as background there will be no colour that can blend in with some existing backgrounc colour in the map.

Therefore, I am trying to use a point pattern fill, but would like to create a gradient in this point pattern. Is this possible?

Comment: I believe the closest option would be a two-color shapeburst fill, with the first color transparent.

Answer (score 1):

+1 to @csk for concept. This is possible, only in roundabout ways.

You would have to utilize the data driven parameters of QGIS, which are impressive.

It is more difficult (to this user) to know how to access the geometry of a 'virtual' symbolized geometry (point pattern fill) than actual feature geometry. Therefor, if you were to create an analogous point layer using grid or random points within polygon, you could then field calculate a point attribute value of the proximity to polygon edge.

Using a *data driven* fill color expression you can independently set the alpha transparency value of a given feature using an expression similar to:

```
set_color_part(@symbol_color,'alpha', 255*("POP"*10)/(maximum("POP")))
```

"POP" in this case is the field which will control transparency.

*Note the yellow-activated *Data Driven Expression* button to the right of fill color. Choose *Edit*.

[image: DataDrivenColor]